# Get index method in LAS/LAZ files using PDAL

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, lidar, pdal, las

I'm playing around with [PDAL](https://pdal.io/about.html) command line interface with point cloud files in both LAS and LAZ formats. I want to know if there is an indexing mechanism in LAZ/LAS files. Is there a way to get this using PDAL.

Answer (score 1):

On PDAL official documentation, I found, [tindex](https://pdal.io/apps/tindex.html) as a way to play around with indexing in LAS/LAZ files. In my case, I needed to use `tindex` in finding the border of a given geography area and I could sort it out with the use ot `tindex`.